# boolean indexing with setting in numpy array

Tags: numpy, indexing

I have numpy array `a` of shape `m,n,3` and `mask` of shape `m,n`. When I try setting `a[mask > 0] = (255, 0, 0)` I get error

```
ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 7401 output values where the mask is true`
```

How can I achieve this functionality in numpy?

Comment: Try [numpy.ma](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you are seeing.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I was indexing with mask that was `m,n,3` shaped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(100,200,3))
mask = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(100,200))
a[mask > 0] = [255,0,0]
# Test
assert np.equal(a[mask > 0], 
    np.ones_like(a[mask > 0])*[255,0,0]).sum() == np.multiply(*a[mask > 0].shape)
```